# Is there any Graph Builder for GStreamer?

Tags: c++, graph, gstreamer

Is there any Graph Builder for GStreamer? So to say you build graph you get code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[gst-editor](http://code.google.com/p/gst-editor/) seems to be something like what you are looking for. It doesn't appear to support generating C++ code, but what it does support is saving XML that can be loaded into your program in the same way that libglade allows you to load Glade GUIs. It looks very intuitive and low-nonsense, judging by the screen shots.

Answer (score 6):

There is gst-editor. But last time I checked it was really buggy and badly maintained.

If you want to design a pipeline quickly you can use the [gst-launch](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-checklist-applications.html) tool. The gst-launch description can then be imported in your code using the [gst_parse_launch](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-GstParse.html) call.